# Calculate maximum path cost for a matrix in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

I am learning c and encountered  maximum cost path question in which

Rules:

1. matrix is n x n size
2. Starting from the cell (bottommost leftmost cell), you want to go to the topmost
   rightmost cell in a sequence of steps. In each step, you can go either right or up from
   your current location.

I tried to solve using dynamic programming and this is the function I have written

```
computecost(int *utr,int n)//utr is the input matrix 
{
 int *str;
 int i,j;
 str=(int *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)//intialization of bottom row
 {
      str[n*(n-1)+j]=utr[n*(n-1)+j];
 }
 for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
 {
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         str[n*i+j]=utr[n*i+j]+max(str[n*(i+1)+j],str[n*(i+1)+(j+1)]);   
     }
 }
 
printf("%d",str[n*0+0]);
 
 return 0;
}
```

and this is the input

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         scanf("%d",&str[n*i+j]);
     }
 }
```

but
for the matrix 5 x5

```
1   4   8   2   9 

32  67  18  42  1 

4   86  12  7   1 

8   4   12  17  44

1   43  11  45  2
```

the desired output is 272 but I am getting 211.

the output matrix for my case

```
  1   43  11  45  2
  51  47  57  62  46
  55  143  74  69  47
  175  210  92  111  52
  211  214  119  113  64
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243028/discussion-on-question-by-user-calculate-maximum-path-cost-for-a-matrix-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not very far to succeed.
In practice, you did not initialize correctly the bottom row.
Moreover, there was a little mistake in the iteration calculation.

This is the corrected code.
As said in a comment, it could be further simplified, by avoiding the use of a new array, simply updating the input array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max (int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int computecost(int *utr,int n) {   //utr is the input matrix 
    int *str;
    str = malloc (n*n*sizeof(int));
    str[n*n - 1] = utr[n*n - 1];
    for (int j = n-2; j >= 0; j--) {    //intialization of bottom row {
        str[n*(n-1)+j] = utr[n*(n-1)+j] + str[n*(n-1)+j+1];       // corrected
    }
    for (int i=n-2; i>=0; i--) {
        str[n*i+n-1] = utr[n*i+n-1] + str[n*(i+1)+n-1];
        for(int j = n-2; j >= 0; j--) {
           str[n*i+j] = utr[n*i+j] + max(str[n*(i+1)+j],str[n*i + j+1]); // corrected
        }
    }
    int cost = str[0];
    free (str);
    return cost;
}

int main() {
    int A[25] = {
        1,43,11,45,2,
        8,4,12,17,44,
        4,86,12,7,1,
        32,67,18,42,1,
        1,4,8,2,9
    };
    int ans = computecost (A, 5);
    printf ("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic programming for this since there are no overlapping sub-problems. Just use a simple recursion.

```
const int n = 5;
int mat[n][n] = {
    {1,4,8,2,9},
    {32,67,18,42,1},
    {4,86,12,7,1},
    {8,4,12,17,44},
    {1,43,11,45,2}
}; // input matrix

int f(int x, int y, int sum){
    if(x == 0 && y == 4)
        return sum;

    int p = 0, q = 0;
    if(x - 1 >= 0)
        p = f(x-1, y, sum + mat[x-1][y]);
    if(y + 1 <= 4)
        q = f(x, y+1, sum+mat[x][y+1]);
    return max(p,q);
}

int main(){
    int maxSum = f(4,0, mat[4][0]);
    printf("%d\n", maxSum);
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to understand the mistake in their code... But probably they will still accept your answer.

Comment: Let me try to explain the solution incase it's needed. Basically you need to go from (4,0) to (0,4) cell in the matrix while taking the path with the maximum sum. So the recursion function's base case is to check if we've reached the  ` x == 0` and `y == 4` . 3rd parameter stores the current sum which includes previous sum of the taken path + cell value (` sum + mat[x-1][y] ` for top and ` sum + mat[x][y-1] for right `), then take the max of these two sums and return it. Hence we get 272, the desired output.

Comment: @Abrar but recursive algorithm has  time order of nearly 2^n . I want to decrease  the time complexity so I chose dynamic programming . Sorry and please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user There is no optimization for this problem since there are no overlapping sub-problems. Correct me if I'm wrong, the complexity is n^2.